# Why is it useful to have a synchronized collection in Java

Tags: java

I have came know that the difference between ArrayList and Vector class is that Vector class is synchronised whereas the ArrayList is not. I know what is synchronization, **but can anyone explain how it is useful in this context?**

Comment: What is synchronization?  Knowing that should give a good clue on why it is useful for collections, or any object for that matter.

Comment: I have got a clue but I don't want to assume it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class ThreadSafeExample {
    private Vector<String> names = new Vector<String>();

    public void addName(String name) {
       names.add(name);
    }
}
```

This class will work fine even if multiple threads call the `addName(..)` method. With `ArrayList`, it won't - you will have missing values.

The performance of `Vector`, `ArrayList` is [benchmarked here](http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2010/12/what-is-faster-jvm-performance.html). Note that there also exists `Collections.synchornizedList(..)` which makes any list synchronized.

Note that this applies when the collection is used as an instance field. If  the vector is declared within a method, then you gain nothing with the synchornization (no other thread can use it anyway). In fact, there is something called "escape analysis", which in this case removes the synchornization if it is not needed. But I think it is not on by default.

Comment: I think you forgot a synchronized somewhere?

Comment: I didn't. That's the point - Vector does not require external synchornization.

Comment: Yeah, OK.  Calling the enclosing class ThreadSafeClass threw me :-)

Answer (score 4):

Synchronization is used in the context of [Concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_%28computer_science%29). [This](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) clearly explains why synchronization is essential:

> Threads communicate primarily by
>   sharing access to fields and the
>   objects reference fields refer to.
>   This form of communication is
>   extremely efficient, but makes two
>   kinds of errors possible: *thread
>   interference* and *memory consistency
>   errors*. The tool needed to prevent
>   these errors is *synchronization*.

Synchronized class/method/instance/statement variables prevents concurrent usage of the synchronized class/method/instance/statement.

> When one thread is executing a
>   synchronized method for an object, all
>   other threads that invoke synchronized
>   methods for the same object block
>   (suspend execution) until the first
>   thread is done with the object.'

[Source](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Vectors are thread-safe (meaning synchronized) while ArrayList aren't. You can allow thread safety by using `Collections.synchronizedList(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

I did not wanted to redirect you, but I have the same thing to say as here: http://manikandanmv.wordpress.com/2009/03/21/vector-vs-arraylist/

> **Vector**
>
> - Vector is thread safe, because vector objects are synchronized which means you can access vector objects from any number of threads at the same time without affecting its data.
> - Due to the above reason, In performance wise Vector is slightly slower than ArrayList
> - Double the size of its internal array when it runs out of space.
>
> **ArrayList**
>
> - ArrayList is just opposite of Vector class. Its not thread safe, suppose if you are using ArrayList instances in multiple threads surely which leads to create some problems while accessing.
> - ArrayList comes from Collection Framework family. So its easy to developers to convert in to any other datastructure formats.
> - Increases its array size by 50 percent.

ArrayList are more preffered and you can externally synchronize them by `Collections.syncronizedList(..)`

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization of a list is necessary if multiple threads may access it concurrently. Synchronization is an unnecessary (but not necessarily significant) cost if only a single thread can access the list.

I personally tend to use ArrayList by default, and synchronize access to it if required.

Using the common List<> interface to refer to instances of Vector or ArrayList allows you to switch implementations more easily.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` was meant to replace `Vector` however it is not thread safe by design. I would suggest only using `ArrayList` and not making use of `Vector` since it was not designed ground up to be part of the Collections. If you need thread safety on your `ArrayList` you can do...

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask what synchronization is useful for? You might enjoy Doug Lea's book [Concurrent Programming in Java](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0201310090).  Although it is slightly dated, it gave a good academic treatment of the issues inherent in multiple threads of execution accessing the same data structures.  For actual application and a more up-to-date treatment, you would read [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0321349601).

As Doug Lea would put it, you want threads of execution to make progress.  But you also want to preserve the integrity of data structures.

In the case of Vector and ArrayList, suppose two threads went to add an item 'at the same time'.  One of the things that needs to be done is that the count of items in the  needs to be incremented.  This is something hidden from you, but is nonetheless important to the collection itself.  It would not do for ThreadA to see that before it added the item, the count was 3, and tried to write 4, but meanwhile ThreadB had already incremented it to 4 and it should now be 5!

Synchronisation is one approach to solving this problem.  Essentially, when two threads attempt to access the same object and it encounters a 'synchronized block' (which sometimes may be an entire method), ThreadB has to wait until ThreadA is finished and 'releases the lock'.  That way, there is no chance of the two threads reading the count and then two threads writing the count.  By forcing an order on the operations of the threads (synchronizing them), there is a read/write followed by another read/write.